# Error while taking input for input file and saving output in output file bye creating task for terminal in vscode

Tags: python-3.x

getting null value as[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBF2R.png)

may task.json is as below

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compile and run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "",
            "args": [
                "python3",
                "${relativeFile}",
                "<",
                "input.txt",
                ">",
                "output.txt"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "never"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "py",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Want can i do to solve this issue?

i only want 8 as ans no null or any other values
i checked the input file for any extra spaces and deleted output file but still same output

Comment: Tag of this question is python, while the question does not cover that. I tried to -tag, but I was not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with my task.json file

```
"command": "cmd",
        "args": [
            "/C",
            "python ${relativeFile} < input.txt > output.txt"
        ]
```

add command as cmd and in args add /C